# Adding simple views in django

Tags: django, django-views

I am getting started on django and this is how my view is looking like

```
from django.template import Context, loader
from datetime import datetime
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello_view(request):
    """ Simple Hello World View """
    t = loader.get_template('helloworld.html')
    c = Context({
        'current_time': datetime.now(),
    })
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))

def detail_view(request):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at detail view")
```

My urls.py file looks like this

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from posted.views import hello_view
#from posted.views import detail_view

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
     url(r'^$', view=hello_view, name='hello_page'),
     #url(r'^$', view=detail_view, name='detail_page'),
    # url(r'^posts/', include('posts.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

When i run the server and visit http://example.com:8000/ ,the hello_view gets displayed.I want my urls to be of the form http://example.com:8000/hello or http://example.com:8000/detail. Do i need .htaccess to achieve that?.

Comment: No, why should you need .htaccess? The [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial04/#amend-urlconf) covers this in detail.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want to trailing slash?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue somewhat with this while i study what Daniel suggested i look at.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    (r'^detail/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="detail.html")),
    # url(r'^posts/', include('posts.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```